# built tcc for armv7 and ran it on android device, where would I put header files?

Tags: android, c, header-files

Hello so I compiled tcc (Tiny C Compiler) with the armv7 cross compiler on Ubuntu, arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. I pushed it to the android bin (/system/bin) and was able to execute it, however I'm missing all of the C header files! Where would I put the arm c header files on a android device? (sorry if this is the wrong community this community is where I guess this question should go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I created the folder /usr/include in root directory (/) and put header files in the include folder, and successfully compiled with header files!